# List index out of range for Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a question regarding the following exercise:

```py
def addstock():
        time = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
        hour = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p")
        query = 'SELECT TotalStock FROM Stocks WHERE name = ? ORDER BY MovementID DESC LIMIT 1'
        parameters = (name.get(),)
        lastrecord = run_query(query, parameters)
        print(float(lastrecord.fetchall()[0][0]))
        print(float(quantity.get()))
        totalstock = (float(lastrecord.fetchall()[0][0])) + (float(quantity.get()))
        query = 'SELECT precio FROM product WHERE name = ?'
        precio = run_query(query, parameters)
        pricequant = precio.fetchall()[0]
        pricequantity = pricequant * quantities
        query = 'SELECT precio FROM product WHERE name = ?'
        parameters = (name.get(),)
        precio = run_query(query, parameters)
        priceforall = pricequant * totalstock
```

In this function, I print `lastrecord.fetchall()[0][0]` and `quantity.get` to make sure they are float. So the program prints in that case: 5.0 for `lastrecord.fetchall` and `quantity.get`

Up to now, no problem, but when I try to us them up, it gives me an error of List Index Out Of Range, so program do not find the value of `lastrecord.fetchall()[0][0]` which 2 lines before I was able to print successfully. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Your posted code does not run: you never call the function.  If we simply remove the `def` line, it dies for many undefined symbols.  We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: You've exhausted the generator with the first call to `.fetchall()`. Subsequent calls return an empty list.

Comment: Store the results of .fetchall() then use that later on, e.g., `rows = lastrecord.fetchall()`. Then you can `rows[0][0]` as many times as you want later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html):

> The method fetches all (or all remaining) rows of a query result set and returns a list of tuples. If no more rows are available, it returns an empty list.

When you first time used `lastrecord.fetchall()[0][0]` all the records of `lastrecord` curser are fetched, so on the second call on `totalstock = (float(lastrecord.fetchall()[0][0])) + (float(quantity.get()))` there is no more rows left for the curser. If you want to reuse the fetched data, store it, then use it anytime you want, like this:

```
all_records = lastrecord.fetchall()
// ...
print(float(all_records[0][0]))
// ...
totalstock = (float(all_records[0][0])) + (float(quantity.get()))
```

Comment: Thanks :D. So I can only use fetchall 1 time. It is weird but clear :D

Comment: @XaviLopezPonte You're welcome, it's not actually weird, it's exactly what cursers should do. Cursers enable us to **iterate** through a set of rows, and when you fully iterated a row set, there is nothing remained, so the second call is empty list.